# SSL protocol seems to be missing in Wireshark

Tags: ssl, wireshark, network-protocols

SSL protocol seems to be missing for me. It doesn't show up in the [preferences menu](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/570942361903955978/571338370131689482/unknown.png) and Wireshark doesn't capture any SSL packets from any program I try. I also had a failed handshake trying to just setup a basic OpenSSL server, but I'm not exactly sure if that's part of the problem, as I didn't even bother fixing it.

Windows 7, latest release of Wireshark. Really not sure what else to add, tried searching around google to no avail. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 21):

The SSL protocol (SSLv2 and SSLv3) hasn't been in use for several years, having been [superseded](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7568) by TLSv1. While some programs still start with SSLv2-compatible handshakes or occassionally use the SSLv2-style record format, they all generally use **TLS** nowadays and the Wireshark configuration page has been renamed accordingly. The display filter is `tls`.

(Yes, HTTPS is HTTP-over-TLS and OpenSSL is actually a TLS library – despite the name, it doesn't even have SSLv2/v3 support in it anymore.)

The Wireshark TLS dissector handles both modern TLSv1.x and the obsolete SSLv2/v3 versions.

[image: Screenshot of Wireshark's TLS settings page]

Comment: Worth pointing out that `SSLv2 and SSLv3` are both considered to be insecure.  Due to inherited weaknesses in the protocol, and today's computing power, makes them extremely vulnerable.  This might not matter depending on your usage case, but it might be important, which means you should only be looking to use solutions that support TLSv1.2+